# Spring cloud data flow - Task - how to pass command line argument

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am having a hard time to make a simple task run successfully in the spring cloud data flow (SCDF). This is what I wanted to do simply.

```
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(
                "Passed argument : " + args[0]
        );
    }
```

I am using the docker-compose installation method for local testing. SCDF seems to pass mariadb as the driver. I am not sure where to override these default values.

[image]

SCDF allows to pass arguments every run. I could pass below argument to override the mariadb driver.

[image]

But it picks the value as the command line argument. There is no way for me to pass the command line argument!!

```
2020-04-02 03:08:32.557  INFO 115 --- [           main] c.v.cloudtask.CloudTaskApplication       : Started CloudTaskApplication in 2.719 seconds (JVM running for 3.267)
Passed argument : --spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
2020-04-02 03:08:32.595 DEBUG 115 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.r.support.SimpleTaskRepository
```

Question:
1) How can i force ti use to mysql driver..and not to use mariadb?
2) how to pass command line arguments?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `docker-compose` files to run the SCDF server locally, you can use docker-compose customization as mentioned [here](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/local/docker-customize/).

If you are starting the standalone SCDF server, you can customize the datasource properties as mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_mysql)

Could you clarify what you mean by:

> But it picks the value as the command line argument. There is no way for me to pass the command line argument!!

You mentioned it picks the value as the command line argument?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it does not clarify. I have already done local docker-compose customization. My concern is - from where spring boot is the passing mariadb driver name.? I want to remove that. If i have to pass --spring.datasour.... to use MySQL, then how can I pass argument to my cloud task. Please see my cloud task in the question.